# decrypting php/openssl on windows 2012

Tags: php, encryption, iis-8

I am being posted a string from a debian/php box which uses openssl to encrypt a string like this:

```
    $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc');
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size);
    $key = mb_substr(hash('sha256', ENCRYPTION_KEY . HMAC_SALT), 0, 32, '8bit');
    $encrypted_string = openssl_encrypt($plain, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $ciphertext = $iv . $encrypted_string;
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext, $key);

    return $hmac . $ciphertext;
```

My server is running IIS on Win 2012r2 and I need a way of decrypting the value (given that the encryption key and hmac are pre-shared and I know them).

I've been looking at the openssl binaries for windows (https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) and had just expected to drop to a shell and do the decryption and grab its result from stdout - but I'm not really sure how (encryption is *not* my thing). I've google/rtfm'd until I turned blue...

Comment: Can you not just use PHP's openssl extension on a Windows PHP distro to decrypt it the same way you encrypt it?

Comment: @RobbieAverill, yeah after looking for any other way I think I'll have to get php installed - otherwise it's in the ugly hack / too hard basket.

Comment: I could only suggest Linux alternatives as I'm not good with Windows shell scripting. I'd just use PHP to be honest